# Leitura e escrita de arquivo Laravel

Tags: php, html5, laravel, arquivo

Estou tentando ler um arquivo que vem de um formulário. Quando envio ele para o Controller, tenho que ler o arquivo e procurar uma linha, se ela existir, adicionar uma linha logo abaixo.

Dúvidas:

1- Consigo localizar no arquivo a frase, mas não estou conseguindo adicionar uma linha logo abaixo.

```
public function adiciona(Request $request){
       /*
        * O campo do form com o arquivo tinha o atributo name="file".
        */
        $file = $request->file('file');




$searchthis = "|C190|000|6102|12,00|36702,99|36702,99|4404,36|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00||";
$matches = array();

$handle = fopen($file, "r");

if ($handle) {
      while (!feof($handle)) {
          $buffer = fgets($handle);
          if (strpos($buffer, $searchthis) !== FALSE) {
              //$matches[] = $buffer;

          }
      }
  fclose($handle);
}

//mostra os resultados:
print_r($matches);

        // Faça qualquer coisa com o arquivo enviado...
}
```

Comment: Já tentou pular a linha com PHP_EOL?

Comment: já consegui pegar a linha que queria, o que falta é comparar essas duas strings, para ver se existe no arquivo

Answer (score 0):

já consegui pegar a linha que queria, o que falta é comparar essas duas strings, para ver se existe no arquivo

```
public function adiciona(Request $request){

$file = $request->file('file');
$busca ="*|C100|1|0|FOR000002301|55|00|001|48950|50190410761127000187550010000489501000489504|23042019|23042019|36702,99|1|0,00|0,00|36702,99|1|0,00|0,00|0,00|36702,99|4404,36|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|";
$arquivo = file($file);

// armazena o que contem a linha 11
$linha_trocada = $arquivo[2561];
$linha_compara = $arquivo[2559];
//dd($linha_compara);
var_dump($linha_compara);
if($linha_compara==$busca){
    dd("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
}
        //print_r($conteudoLinha);


}
```